# Control the number of displayed rows in a dropdown

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to control the number of displayed rows in a DropDownList control? I'd like it to only display 10 rows, but it defaults to 30. This causes the list to appear higher than the control instead of below it because of its position on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ASP.NET renders a DropDownList control as a `<select>` then there is no way to control the number of rows shown when the `<select>` is opened, it is browser-implementation dependant.

A quick test shows that IE 6 reveals 27 items from a 27 item list, Safari for Windows 3.2.1 reveals 22, Firefox 2 reveals 20 and Opera 9.6.2 reveals 16. The number revealed may even depend on the total number of items, but I didn't bother to test that because it is pretty obvious this isn't something you're going to be able to control.

Adding `size="..."` to the control will make the drop-down list a fixed size and it will no longer be a "drop-down list" (assuming you can even do that).

The only solution to this seems to be to implement a JavaScript-based pull-down control of your own, or buy or download one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do pagination on the data source for the drop down list using PagedDataSource and set the PageSize to 10.

Comment: I have not been able to get a sample working. If you could elaborate with some code, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Note: 
I have not tried this using code

Add "size" attribute with "10" as value to show 10 rows in the dropdown.

```
<asp:dropdownlist size="10" ...>
```

Does this work? (I am guessing it,as dropdownlist is SELECT tag in html)

Comment: I am sorry, size would turn it into a list :(